# Process: com.tarang.grocery, PID: 7824 java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()

Tags: javascript, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

private void loadShopInfo(ModelOrderUser modelOrderUser, final HolderOrderUser holder) {
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
ref.child(modelOrderUser.getOrderTo())
.addValueEventListener (new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange (@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
String shopName = ""+dataSnapshot.child("shopName").getValue();
holder.shopNameTv.setText(shopName);
}

```
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            } );
}
```

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: It looks like your `modelOrderUser.getOrderTo()` is returning `null`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yess the error is their what to do